# Use a js file inside karate-config.js

Tags: karate

I have a basic-auth.js file with a function auth().

I want to use that function inside karate-config.js, which is the best way? Is it using karate.call?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
var fun = read('basic-auth.js');
var res = fun();
```